# Apache2 mod_rewrite Clean URL - working, but files not accessible

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

Server: Debian Jessie
Apache: 2.4.9-1
PHP: 5.5

What I want is all non-files and non-directories to redirect to index.php where I handle them myself. Due to the nature of my project I must work from within a virtual host.

I'm using virtual hosting (vHosts) along with mod_rewrite in a web project I'm working on. Here's the vHost file...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName foo.com

        ServerAlias www.foo.com

        ServerAdmin admin@foo.com

        DocumentRoot /srv/foo/main/www/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

                RewriteEngine on

                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]

        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

The vHost is working as expected, and the rewrite rules are redirecting requests to index.php as expected. However when I try to access files on the server, for example:

```
foo.com/css/style.css
```

located in:

```
/srv/foo/main/www/css/style.css
```

my request is redirected to index.php

This is strange as the rewrite condition statements is supposed to fix that.

All folder permissions are set to 755, all files to 644.

I have been able to confirm without a doubt that the rewrite conditions are matching when they should not be. I was able to see this by looking at apache's error log with debug output enabled for mod_rewrite.

Why are the two RewriteCond statements incorrectly matching?

Are they perhaps not seeing the vHost DocumentRoot?

UPDATE: Turning the rewrite engine OFF allows me to get to the file I'm testing with. IE, my URI is correct. I know my path is good, the conditions are just failing for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using Apache 2.4 with virtual hosts & wanting to use mod_rewrite inside said vHost with rewrite conditions that need to check files or folders inside the vHost, this is how to do the rewrite conditions...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

       <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

                RewriteEngine on

                RewriteCond %{CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
                RewriteCond %{CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d

                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]

        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

I came up with this and it seems to be working well.

The explanation...

`%{CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` will give you a context sensitive document root. IE, the document root AFTER virtual hosting has been applied. But it will not give you the URI so we need to add the `%{REQUEST_URI}` to finish the job.

CONTEXT_DOC_ROOT == /srv/foo/main/www

REQUEST_URI == /css/style.css

CONTEXT_DOC_ROOT + REQUEST_URI == /srv/foo/main/www/css/style.css

The rest is easy. Awesome sauce. Hope this helps!